# Bottles aplication doesn't start | La aplicaion Botellas no inicia

Tags: bottle

I have a problem to use Bottles aplication, i just does not start. I'm using...

Hola  a todos, tengo problemas para iniciar la aplicacion Botellas, simplemente no inicia. Estoy usando...

OS: Ubuntu MATE 22.04.4 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 6.5.0-18-generic

Shell: bash 5.1.16

Resolution: 1920x1080

DE: MATE 1.26.0

WM: Metacity (Marco)

Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3]

Icons: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3]

Terminal: mate-terminal

Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 15

CPU: Intel i3 550 (4) @ 3.200GHz

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 210

Memory: 2267MiB / 3771MiB

Some idea to start to see what its happening? | Alguna idea para empezar a ver que está sucediendo?

Comment: Please [edit] with logs: https://docs.usebottles.com/utilities/logs-and-debugger

Comment: Lets see I have copied de command exposed on properties after made a shortcut to desktop and I get the next data | Veamos, copié el comande expuesto en propiedades despué de hace un acceso directo al escritorio conseguí la siguiente información. || --   patrick@patrick-pc:~$ /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=bottles --file-forwarding com.usebottles.bottles @@u %u @@ |    
20:37:54 (ERROR) Unable to load libGLX_nvidia.so.0  |  
20:37:54 (WARNING) Unable to locate libGLX_nvidia   |   
URI no válido (sintaxis: bottles:run/<bottle>/<program>)

Answer (score 1):

[Bottles is missing the 64-bit Flatpak Nvidia driver.](https://github.com/bottlesdevs/Bottles/issues/3133#issuecomment-1863175757) Let's install it:

```bash
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-545-29-06
```